# How can I make sure my user interface adheres to MSAA standards?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, automation, coded-ui-tests, msaa

I would like to understand how I can identify the level of MSAA adherence in the applications that I work with. I would also like to know the most practical route to ensuring the your user interface is adheres to MSAA standards.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: There is no simple answer. There is some information on supporting Coded UI with custom control in the "Extending Coded UI Test" part of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx

Microsoft has a forum for accessibility and automation, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/b2fe3999-d898-4030-a49c-a75cdbf88495/welcome-to-the-windows-accessibility-and-automation-development-forum?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like Inspect32 or AccExplorer to check which MSAA fields are supported...

Tom